# How can I override an external css?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, yui

I'm using the YUI Javascript framework, which gives me a calendar widget that comes with a css file. These are included at the top of my Site.Master file. I'd like to override the style associated with the widget, but I can't seem to figure out how.

I've tried adding an entry for the widget's class:

```
.yui-calendar
{
 height:10;
 width:10;
}
```

in both my local css file, and in a style tag in the master file. When I use Internet Explorer's developer tools to look at the page's style, it lists 3 sources for that class's style: my local css file, the ASP.Net view for the page, and the external YUI css. It never references the master file, and even when I've got the class in my local css file, the style doesn't appear in the developer tools list of styles (I don't see .yui-calendar in the list it gives me).

So the question is, what's the proper way to override the style for the class coming in from the external css file?

Comment: I usually include my own site's styling AFTER, so I can do overrides if I need.

Comment: I still don't see my style when looking at the local css file using the debug tool, even with the important tags. Maybe I'm not getting a correct match? YUI generates this table: <table class="yui-calendar y2009" id="calendar" cellSpacing="0"> and the style I'm adding is .yui-calendar. I've tried yui-calendar y2009, as well. I'm very new to css, so maybe this isn't the proper way to match that class?

Comment: Try something simple: in IE, clear your cache, and then shift-reload the page.  IE has always been *awful* about holding onto cached versions of CSS files even when they've been modified.

Comment: No luck. Does it look like I'm adding the style in the correct place, with the correct name? It's very odd that I wouldn't see it at all, come to think of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try adding units to that CSS:

```
.yui-calendar
{
 height:10px;
 width:10px;
}
```

You need units for values other than 0 in CSS.

Comment: Finally, after playing with this for so long, something so little has fixed it. Good catch! My styles show up now, and modifying them has an effect on the calendar. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The visible CSS is determined in this order:

1)External style sheet

2)Internal style sheet (style tags)

3)Inline Style

4)User Defined Style Sheet

5)External Style Sheet with !important

6)Internal Style Sheet with !important

7)Inline style with !important

8)User Defined style with !important

The lowest one on that list which is declared will be the one that is used.

As a note, **it is bad form to use !important** as this can override user style sheets used by the visually impaired and can drastically reduce accessability/usability for these groups.

Comment: @Chris, I don't know that I agree with your blanket declaration that it's bad form to use `!important` -- it's impossible to cede the use of `!important` to only screen readers.  Given your list of the order of CSS priority, it stands to reason that screen readers should always apply styles at the highest priority (the lowest item on your list, user-defined styles with `!important`), so that they can always allow their users to enforce the priority of the screen reader's styles over those of the designer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use `!important` (not sure though). See [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

Answer (score 3):

An inline style overrides any CSS style declaration.

So something like this:

```
<div class="yui-calendar" style="height:10px;width:10px;"></div>
```

The inline style would override any external definition in this case.

As Jason S noted also, the `!important` attribute is a way for your local stylesheet rule to override any external declarations. Actually, this is probably the better of the 2, but they both work.

Comment: great, thanks for explaining! CSS is not my strong point, but I just ran into a problem recently involving "!important" so it's fresh in my mind.

Comment: Just to be clear, see the answer by Chris Sobolewski -- your contention that "an inline style overrides any CSS style declaration" isn't entirely correct, user-defined CSS will always override inline styles.

Comment: @delfuego - thanks for the heads up. It is worth mentioning for sure, but in practice, they are not commonly used, and really there is nothing you can do as a developer during development if someone wants to override your styles with one. But technically, yes that is part of the correct answer :P

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `!important` at the end of each line of your style definition:

```
.yui-calendar
{
  height: 10 !important;
  width: 10 !important;
}
```

This will declare that your style definitions are higher-priority than the YUI ones.  The W3c document explaining the use of `!important` is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules).

Answer (score 1):

Paul Waite's answer should probably sort it out.

If not have you checked that YUI is not creating either inline styling or some other element that you're not targeting yet?